# UnicodeDecodeError parsing file with for loop python3

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.4, unicode-string

I got UnicodeDecodeError when I loop line in file.

```
with open(somefile,'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        #do something
```

This happend when I use python 3.4. 
In general I have some files which contain some no UTF-8 chars. I want to parse file line by line and find line where problem apper and got exact index in line where such non utf-8 appeard. I have ready code for it but it works uner python 2.7.9 but under python 3.4 I got UnicodeDecodeError when for loop is executed.
Any ideas???

Comment: `for ind,line in enumerate(f, 1):print(ind)` will give you the line number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to open the file in binary mode and decode the lines one at a time. Try this:

```
with open('badutf.txt', 'rb') as f:
    for i, line in enumerate(f,1):
        try:
            line.decode('utf-8')
        except UnicodeDecodeError as e:
            print ('Line: {}, Offset: {}, {}'.format(i, e.start, e.reason))
```

Here is the result I get in Python3:

```
Line: 16, Offset: 6, invalid start byte
```

Sure enough, line 16, position 6 is the bad byte.

Comment: I almost did this, but ended up using `encoding='utf-8'` as an argument to `open()` and that solved the problem for me.

Comment: Sadly, this did not work for me.  I'm getting a `UnicodeDecodeError` error, but it shows clean when running the text file through your code.